# How use perl to process a file whose format is similar to unicode?

Tags: perl, file, encode

I have a legacy program, and after running it, it will generate a log file. Now I need to analysis this log file.

But the file format is very strange. Please see the following,I used vi to open it, it looks like an unicode file, but it is not FFFE started. after I used notepad open it, save it and open again, I found that the FFFE is added by notepad. Then I can use command 'type log.txt > log1.txt" to convert the whole file to ANSI format. Later in perl, I can use /TDD/ in perl to search what I need.

But now, I can't deal with this file format.

Any comment or idea will be very appreciated.

```
0000000: 5400 4400 4400 3e00 2000 4c00 6f00 6100  T.D.D.>. .L.o.a.
```

After notepad save it

```
0000000: fffe 5400 4400 4400 3e00 2000 4c00 6f00  ..T.D.D.>. .L.o.

open STDIN, "< log.txt";
while(<>)
{
  if (/TDD/)
  {
    # Add my logic.
  }
}
```

I have read the thread which is very useful, but still can't resolve my problem.
[How can I open a Unicode file with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461737/how-can-i-open-a-unicode-file-with-perl)

I can't add answer, so I edit my thread.

Thanks Michael, 
I tried your script but got the following error. I checked my perl version is 5.1, OS is windows 2008.

```
* ascii
* ascii-ctrl
* iso-8859-1
* null
* utf-8-strict
* utf8
UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM 5400 at test.pl line 12.
```

**Update**

I tried the UTF-16LE with the command:

```
perl.exe open.pl utf-16le utf-16 <my log file>.txt
```

but I still got the error like

```
UTF-16LE:Partial character at open.pl line 18, <$fh> line 1824.
```

also, I tried utf-16be, got the same error.

If I used utf-16, I will got the error

```
UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM 5400 at open.pl line 18.
```

open.pl line 18

```
is "print while <$fh>;"
```

Any idea?

Updated: 5/11/2011. 
Thank you guys for your help. I resolved the problem. 
I found that the data in log file are not UTF-16 after all. So, I had to write a .net project by visual studio. It will read the log file with UTF-16 and write to a new file with UTF-8. And then I used perl script to parse the file and generate result data. It worked now.

So, if any of you know how to use perl read a file with many garbage data, please tell me, thank you very much.

e.g. garbage data sample

```
tests.cpp:34)
਍吀䐀䐀㸀 䰀漀愀搀椀渀最 挀挀洀挀漀爀攀⸀搀氀
```

use hex reader to open it:

```
0000070: a88d e590 80e4 9080 e490 80e3 b880 e280  ................
0000080: 80e4 b080 e6bc 80e6 8480 e690 80e6 a480  ................
0000090: e6b8 80e6 9c80 e280 80e6 8c80 e68c 80e6  ................
00000a0: b480 e68c 80e6 bc80 e788 80e6 9480 e2b8  ................
```

Comment: May this be of some help: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=615796

Comment: Have you tried specifying different encodings for stream reading?

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you linked to tells you exactly what you need to do to read your UCS-2LE encoded file. I just tried it and it worked for me. - Be more specific for what reason you "can't resolve".

Comment: Orionpax, don't post follow-up questions as answers. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I tried different encodings including UTF16-LE, UTF16-BE, UCS-2LE, UCS-2BE,etc., but I still got the same error 
****:Partial character at open.pl line 23, <$fh> line 1824.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file seems to be encoded in UTF-16LE. The bytes notepad adds are called "Byte Order Mark", or just BOM.

Here's how you can read your file using Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
# list loaded encodings
print STDERR map "* $_\n", Encode->encodings;
# read arguments
my $enc = shift || 'utf16';
die "no files :-(\n" unless @ARGV;
# process files
for ( @ARGV ) {
    open my $fh, "<:encoding($enc)", $_ or die "open $_: $!";
    print <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
# loaded more encodings now
print STDERR map "* $_\n", Encode->encodings;
```

Proceed like this, taking care to supply the correct encoding for your file:

```
perl open.pl utf16 open.utf16be.txt
perl open.pl utf16 open.utf16le.txt
perl open.pl utf16le open.utf16le.nobom.txt
```

Here's the revised version following tchrist's suggestions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

# read arguments
my $enc_in  = shift || die 'pass file encoding as first parameter';
my $enc_out = shift || die 'pass STDOUT encoding as second parameter';
print STDERR "going to read files as encoded in: $enc_in\n";
print STDERR "going to write to standard output in: $enc_out\n";
die "no files :-(\n" unless @ARGV;

binmode STDOUT, ":encoding($enc_out)"; # latin1, cp1252, utf8, UTF-8

print STDERR map "* $_\n", Encode->encodings; # list loaded encodings

for ( @ARGV ) { # process files
    open my $fh, "<:encoding($enc_in)", $_ or die "open $_: $!";
    print while <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}

print STDERR map "* $_\n", Encode->encodings; # more encodings now
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried but got the error like
`UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM 5400 at test.pl line 12`.

the line on `print <$fh>;`

Comment: @Orionpax, in Perl, the `utf16` encoding expects a BOM, because it could be either big or little endian.  Try using `UTF-16LE` instead.

Comment: Then you ran it on the file without BOM. Going to update my example.

Comment: Don’t use `print <$fh>` because it sucks in the whole file before it starts printing, which is not scalable.  Use `print while <$fh>` and make sure you first `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")` or the equivalent.

Comment: @tchrist - Thanks, good points again. Going to update my example script.

Comment: thank you guys, I will try it soon later and update the thread. :)

Comment: Michael, tchrist, and cjm I tried the UTF-16LE with the command: perl.exe open.pl utf-16le utf-16 .txt but I still got the error like

UTF-16LE:Partial character at open.pl line 18, <$fh> line 1824.
also, I tried utf-16be, got the same error. If I used utf-16, I will got the error

UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM 5400 at open.pl line 18.
open.pl line 18 is "print while ;"

Any idea?

Comment: So what's up in line 1824? Your data might not be valid UTF-16 after all. Repeat the test using minimal data and make sure you save your file with the correct encoding and invoke the script supplying the correct encoding. If that works correctly, it strongly suggests a data problem.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, you are right. I also found that the data are not be UTF-16 after all. So, I have to write a .net project by visual studio. Read the log file with UTF-16 and write a file with UTF-8. And then use perl script to parse the file. It worked.